# How to do multiple value replacement in a multiple line at one time

Tags: perl

Lets say I have multiples like this

My input lines:

```
"stack overflow version {5} my new version"
"stack exchnage version {10} my new version"
"perl  scripting version 5.14 my new version"
"segmentaion falult happen {5} if the memory is not freed"
" my college 30 new xxxx"
```

I want to replace value inside parenthesis in all line at one time.

My Approaches:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $old_parameter='stack overfolw version';
my $new_parameter;
my $old_value={5};
my $new_value='20 ';
my $filename ='input.txt'

open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "Couldn't open input file: $!";

while ( <$fh> ) 
{
    if (/$old_parameter/ and /$old_value/) 
    {
        s/$old_value/$new_value/;
    }
}
```

output:

```
stack overflow version {20} my new version; #values change from 5 to 20
```

Now I have hard coded the value which is 20 but what I am looking for I will store the value (1..100) into some array from there I will pick the value based on each line that I want to replace.

For that I need to match line then I have to do replace.

Then what would be the best approach ?

Comment: `s/(...)/ calculate_new_value($1) /eg`

Comment: (1) You opened a file with `open`, and got a "_filehandle_" `$fh`, which is now associated with that file and can be used to work with it.  Now you have to use _that filehandle_, not some "FH".  So -- `while (<$fh>)`. Note also that you need those parenthesis around `<$fh>`. (2) The `if ($old_parameter) ...` statement needs parenthesis _around the whole condition_, so it should be `if ($old_parameter and $old_value)`.  (3) Your `s/...` is missing the closing `/`, should be `s/.../.../`. // If you in fact know this then please make sure that you post correct code, that you actually use.

Comment: @ikegami what I understand from you point I need to use regex and make a group and that value will be extracted $1  but regex for multiple line will be complex .if you kindly tell me with some example.Thanks

Comment: I can't understand your question, and your Perl code won't compile. What do you mean by, for instance, `while<FH>`, and what is in `input.txt`?

Comment: @Abhishek At this point I would urge you to work through some Perl tutorial -- choose what you like, there is a lot out there, excellent introductory books or online material.  There is a lot of the most basic things which aren't right in what you post, and getting bits and pieces in this way is not a good way to learn.  If, on the other hand, you know these basics and still post completely broken code then I'd like to suggest just this one more time that you do your best to post good questions.  This includes the best code that you can come up with.

Comment: `$_ = "abcdcba"; s/([bc])/ uc($1)."!" /eg;`

Comment: My snippets were written under the assumption that the value with which to replace varies, but a re-reading of the question indicates that might not be the case. This question --like all others by this author-- is unclear.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks I got some inputs from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now the question has assumed form. I take it that you want to change the number in `{ }` on a particular line in the file. The posted code got close and I'll comment on basics and complete it.

Since we now find the number inside `{ }` there is no need for the hard-coded `$old_value`. In order to identify the desired line you need to match the `$old_parameter` so the condition becomes `if (/$old_parameter/)`. A comment on [regex matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Simple-word-matching) follows, related only to what is used in the code. Please read documentation and books for more.

Consider `while (my $line = <$fh>)`. A line is read from the file via `$fh` by the [*diamond operator `<>`*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) and assigned to a variable `$line`. If you leave out the variable and write only `while (<$fh>)` then the line is assigned to a special variable called `$_`.  This variable is often used as a default in Perl. See [General Variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables).

To check whether a pattern is in a variable, to "*match*" it, we say `$var =~ m/$patt/`. This returns true or false in *scalar context* while in *list context* it returns the matches. See [Extracting Matches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches). A pattern is best placed into a variable by `$patt = qr(...)`. Our line is in `$_` so we need `$_ =~ m/$patt/`, where `m` may be omitted. Regex also allows a shortcut, since it works by default on `$_`, and we may say `/$patt/`.  Thus `if (/.../)`.

Now consider [substitution](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl). To find a pattern and replace it we say `$var =~ s/$patt/$repl/`. This changes `$var` "*in-place*", meaning that after that statement `$var` is changed. If the `$patt` wasn't found in `$var` nothing happens to it. With our line in `$_` we again need `$_` instead of `$var`, but the same shortcut works and we can say `s/$patt/$repl/`.

Your code has this – but it doesn't do anything with it. The result is never given by the program. An easy way is to print every line and the output can be redirected to a file. Or write lines to a file.

Now for the needed regex.  You want a number inside of `{ }`.  According to the data you show it is the only such pattern in the line. Then this will do

```
s/ \{ \s* \d+ \s* \} /{$new_value}/x;
```

The `/x` allows us to use spaces for readibilty. (Otherwise they would be looked for in the string!)  A digit is matched by `\d`, and `+` means all that come together, but at least one. In `a123b` it matches `123`, in `a12b3c` it matches `12`. The `{` and `}` are escaped since they have a special meaning in a regex. The `\s*` allows for any number of spaces, or for none.

The replacement side of the regex says to replace all that has been matched with `{$new_value}`.  There we don't have to escape `{`, `}`. If you need to *capture* (remember) what has been matched place the pattern in between `()`. Here you can say

```
s/ (\{ \s*) (\d+) (\s* \}) /$1$new_value$3/x;
```

and have the original spaces preserved. The first capture is stored in `$1`, the second in `$2`, etc. If the `$new_value` changes during the loop you can compute it before the substitution.

Please see the answer by [Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern) and the technique offered in a comment by [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami).

Then we only need to print the line.  The full program

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

my $old_parameter = 'stack overflow version';
my $new_value = 20;

my $filename = 'input.txt';

open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

while ( <$fh> ) 
{
    if (/$old_parameter/) 
    {
        s/\{\s* (\d+) \s*\}/{$new_value}/x;
    }
    print;
}
```

The `print;` uses the same default, `$_`, and means `print $_;`.  It is after the condition so that all lines are printed, changed or not. A few other errors have been fixed. An amusing one is the following: your `$old_parameter` has "*stack over**folw** version*" (misspelled) so it *never* matches the line.

Finally, please read through [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), or better yet, through a nice chapter on regular expressions from *a book or a tutorial that you are working with*.

Comment: Thanks you very much for clearly explain me in details.

Comment: In your 4th paragraph you wrote `$patt = qx(...)`. I just fixed that to `$patt = qr(...)`. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @PerlDog  Thank you very much! That's in fact a bad error, `qx` would try to _do_ something with whatever is given to it!  Thank you!

Comment: @Abhishek  You are welcome. If questions come please let me know.

Comment: @zdim. I have regex "my ($f2) = / \S \s+ ( \{ [^{}]+ \} |\{(\d+)\} | \s* ) /xg "with this expression I am unable to extract value from this line "trch_type PCH { 7} Uint8,unsigned char"  when I try to extract value from this line it says $f2 is uninitialized..

Comment: @Abhishek  That is a variation of an answer you got before, right?  Please try to work through that answer, step by step, using some documentation or a book, and online searches when needed. I don't know the context of what you are asking here. As for extracting the number from the line you show, you can use the exact regex in this answer, but with `m/` operator instead of `s/`.  See this in [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), in the section [Extracting Matches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches).

Answer (score -2):

> *I want to replace value inside parenthesis and the value is not
>   constant it will be vary by file by file.*

What you're looking for are "character classes" or "character sets". Regexes can match against sets of characters like numbers, letters, and such. Many are built in, and you can specify your own.

- `\d` matches a digit.
- `\w` matches a digit or letter.
- `[abc]` matches the letters a, b, or c.
- `[^abc]` matches anything *but* the letters a, b, or c.

For more on that, see the [Perl Regex Tutorial on Using Character Classes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes).

Normally these match exactly one character. There are various ways to say how many to match.

- `*` says to match 0 or more.
- `+` says one or more.
- `?` says zero or one.
- `{3,}` says to match three or more.
- `{3,5}` says between three and five.

They go on the end of whatever you're matching like `\d+` means "match 1 or more digits".

For more on that, see the [Perl Regex Tutorial on Matching Repetitions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-repetitions).

Putting them together you get `/\{\d+\}/` or more cleanly `m[ \{ \d+ \} ]x` meaning one or more digits between braces. Braces have to be escaped to not confuse them with the `{3,5}` repetition syntax. The `x` on the end means to ignore whitespace so spaces can be used for formatting the regex. And [`m[ ... ]`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) is an alternative way to write regexes to avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

Search and replace uses the same syntax on it's left side, so `s[ \{ \d+ \} ][ the replacement ]x`.

Comment: @Borodin "*I want to replace value inside parenthesis and the value is not
constant it will be vary by file by file.*" The OP appears to not know about regex character classes and regex meta characters in general. Now they do.

Comment: Then, unless you are willing to clarify via a comment dialogue, that should be quoted as the pretext of your answer. Answers are specific, and not meant to spread useful knowledge in general.

Comment: @Borodin I'm way ahead of you. And this is a specific answer, but I'm not going to write their code for them. Possibly the question would be considered trivial, but people have to know what they don't know before they can know what to look for.

Comment: @Borodin sorry .I have edited my question and want to do value replacement all the line at one time.

Comment: *"I'm way ahead of you"* Maybe. So you understand the question and could rewrite it properly so that it is clear to the rest of us, but choose not to? If so then I think you're obliged to make that edit. Stack Overflow is about providing a library of solutions to programming problems, and answering a question that you leave obscured isn't cricket.

Comment: @Borodin Umm... their question needs a lot of answers. I carved out one. What they probably need is a Perl tutor.

Comment: @Schwern: I am sure that they need a Perl tutor, but even in that vacuum I am certain that your answer would be useful if you clarified the question that you imagined you were responding to. Without that clarification you have written abstract philosophy, and I don't understand your reluctance to improve your contribution.

Comment: @Borodin [Let's have this discussion in chat please](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46138/outside).

Comment: @Schwern: Sorry, I am in Thailand and it's about 4:00am here. I'm also relying on a satellite connection that I doubt will be recompensed. A new question maybe?